# Rails - opacity toggle on dropdown menu icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coffeescript

I created an onclick dropdown menu when a user clicks the settings.svg icon.

Currently, when a user hovers over this settings icon, the opacity changes on the icon from 0.3 (the default opacity) to 0.5.

I am struggling to extend this behaviour. When a user clicks on the settings icon, it's opacity should change from 0.3 to 0.5. It should stay at this 0.5 opacity until a user either clicks on the icon itself again or elsewhere on the page - returning to 0.3.

Any help would be great - thank you!

**application.html.erb**

```
<ul class="navigation-bar">

<div class="navigation-bar-right-inset">
 <li class="navigation-bar-right" id="drop"> <span class="settings"> <a href="#"> <img class="#" src="/assets/settings.svg"> </a> </span>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li> <%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_registration_path, method: :get %> </li>
    <li> <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_url, method: :delete %> </li>   
  </ul>
 </li>
</div>

</ul>
```

**posts.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
 $("#drop").click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).find(".dropdown").fadeToggle "fast"

$(document).on "click", (e) ->
  $trigger = undefined
  $trigger = $("#drop")
  $(".dropdown").fadeOut "fast" if $trigger isnt e.target and not $trigger.has(e.target).length
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation-bar-right .home img:hover, .navigation-bar-right .settings img:hover { opacity: 0.5; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a class called "active" to #drop element everytime the user clicks on it.. if you use jQuery it'll probably look like so:

```
jQuery ->
 $("#drop").click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).addClass("active").find(".dropdown").fadeIn "fast"

$(document).on "click", (e) ->
  $("#drop").removeClass("active").find(".dropdown").fadeOut "fast"
```

Also you can update the css a bit like so:

```
.navigation-bar-right .home img:hover, 
.navigation-bar-right .settings img:hover,
#drop.active .settings img 
{ 
    opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

"#drop.active .settings img" means target the setting image to be opacity 0.5 when the class active is added to #drop, so when the :active: class is removed via jQuery, it will go back to 0.3 unless user hovers over it

I actually prefer to do the fading in and out via CSS transform, but since you did it via jQuery i thought this might be an easier solution for you :)

Good luck!

Comment: I think this approach is better than mine, use it instead :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
do ->
 isActive = false
 activeValue = 0.5
 disabledValue: 0.3
 $dropDownWrapper = $('#drop') # We could use $(event.delegateTarget) inside the event too but i think its more performant this way

 $dropDownWrapper.on 'click', 'img', (e)-> 
   if isActive = !isActive
     $dropDownWrapper.fadeTo(activeValue)
   else
     $dropDownWrapper.fadeTo(disabledValue)
```

I haven't test it, not sure if the syntax is ok, provide a jsfiddle for you original example and i'll modify it with this code, or test it on your end and let me know if it works